# Flutter PagedListView not keep dynamic widgets when rendering

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter, I use `PageListView` for listing large data set from the backend [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination). and I need to group data set by date so I try to add the date using Text widget inside the PageListView widgets. but when load next page, I added Text widgets disappear here is my code, please suggest me the solution

part of the build method

```dart
 Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                  child: PagedListView<int, Content>(
                      pagingController: _pagingController,
                      builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Content>(
                          itemBuilder: (context, item, index) {
                        bool _flag = false;
                        if (!_dateMap.containsKey(item.date.toString())) {
                          _dateMap.putIfAbsent(
                              item.date.toString(), () => item.date);
                          _flag = true;
                        }
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Visibility(
                              visible: _flag,
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 15),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    item.date
                                                .difference(DateTime.now())
                                                .inDays ==
                                            0
                                        ? 'Today'
                                        : item.date
                                                    .difference(DateTime.now())
                                                    .inDays ==
                                                -1
                                            ? 'Yesterday'
                                            : DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy')
                                                .format(item.date)
                                                .toString(),
                                    style:
                                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.5, bottom: 2.5),
                              child: AccountTitle2(
                                reference: item.reference.toString(),
                                accountNo: item.accountNo,
                                transactionType: item.narration,
                                //format.parse(item.time)
                                date: item.date.toString(),
                                time: item.time,
                                //format.parse(item.time).toString(),
                                withdraw: item.withdraw,
                                deposit: item.deposit,
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      })),
                ),
              )
```

here is the example output I need

```
Today

 - Item 1
 - Item 2
 - Item 3

Yesterday 

 - Item 4
 - Item 5
 - Item 6

10-10-2020

 - Item 7
 - Item 8
 - Item 9
```

Comment: Hello there, honestly i'm having trouble understanding the issue. Also, the partial code is not helping me. Sorry but I would need some complete code that specifically targets your question.

Comment: @RukshanJS I update description